# Validate field before DataTransformer is applied

Tags: symfony, validation

In my Symfony application, I have an event entity with an address. This address should be available for many events, so I added a `ManyToOne`-relation.

The `address` entity contains 3 fields (`street`, `zipcode` and `city`), but I would like to have only 1 text input with typeahead for the `address` in my form `EventType`. So I created a `DataTransformer` to do so.

Via an AJAX Request, I recieve the addresses and insert them. If a new address is entered I would like to create a new Database record. My problem now would be the validation for the new entered address.

My `DataTransformer` looks like this:

```php
class StringToAddressTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface {

    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    private $om;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $om
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om){
        $this->om = $om;
    }

    public function transform($addrobj){
        if (!$addrobj) {
            return null;
        }

    return (string)$addrobj;
    }

    public function reverseTransform($address){

        if (null === $address) {
            return "";
        }

        preg_match('/^([A-Z][-A-Z ]+)\s+(\d+), (\d{5}) ([A-Z]+)$/i', $address, $res);

        $street = $res[1] . ' '. $res[2];
        $zipcode = $res[3];
        $city = $res[4];    

        $addrobj = $this->om->getRepository('FSchubert\SiyabongaBundle\Entity\Address')->findOneBy(array(
            'street' => $street, 'zipcode' => $zipcode, 'city' => $city
        ));

        if(is_null($addrobj)){
            $addrobj = new Address();
            $addrobj->setStreet($street);
            $addrobj->setZipcode($zipcode);
            $addrobj->setCity($city);
        }

    return $addrobj;
    }
}
```

It all works out fine, but I have absolutely no validation for the entered address.

I tried adding a constraint in the form class but since the `DataTransformer` is called on `bindRequest()` it appeares to me that the validation-constraint is ignored.

Basically, I want form validation in my `DataTransformer` or any way to validate a non-existend field. If I call the RegEx-Validator manually what would my code look like? Or is there another (better) way to achive what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found an answer. It is by far not the best way. I just removed all fields from the Address-Entity except for one string `addressstring`. Now I can map multiple events to one location and make propper ajax-calls. But unfortunaly I can nolonger determine the city, street or zipcode of each address. This works fine but is, as I stated not the solution. I avoided the real problem... but it works.